# How to conclude a question

Tags: discussion, support

I am new to this site, and I need some help on how to interact with the other users.

I asked a question about logistic regression, which was answered. I was just about to reply and say "thank you", when I saw the instruction message stating that one must not say things like "thanks". I am surprised; it seems to me that saying "thank you" is a friendly way of relating to other users and also lets the other person know that the answer was helpful.

In addition, I didn't see any option to conclude the question and confirm that the answer was a good one.

I look forward to some help.

Cheers,

Jerome Smith

Comment: You simply upvote the answer. That's reward enough for the guy!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems kind of oppressive that the StackExchange convention is to not bother signing off a question with "thank you, I'm looking forward to your answers" but the culture of SE prizes direct, efficient questions, and people go so far as to delete extraneous communication like this.

I'm not sure whether you mean you had this text edited out of your question though. I think it's appropriate to upvote a good answer, and maybe comment on the answer saying it's a good reply. You don't need to do anything else. In fact you shouldn't do other things like try to "answer" and say another answer is good; that's wrong. Or edit your question or the answer with a reply.